# Issue while using preg_match_all inside loop over a column value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, preg-match-all

I want to use `preg_match_all()` for "msg" column values inside loop.

But in my loop it won't work with all "msg" column values, working only with last one.

Following is the code I have written:

```
$query = "SELECT email_id, msg FROM emailtry";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    printf("%s (%s) \n\n\n",$obj->email_id, $obj->msg);
    $string = $obj->msg;
    
    if (is_array($result) || is_object($result) ){  
        foreach($result as $result){
            if (preg_match_all("/Dynamic Screen:\s+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\s+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", $string, $notificationtype)){
                var_dump($notificationtype);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
            if (preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", $string, $bodylogonused)){
                var_dump($bodylogonused);
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this: foreach($result as $result). Try giving them different names. I don't know if that will help your issue or not but maybe.

Comment: When already `while` is executing then what's the need of `foreach()` inside it?

Comment: I have voted this question to be Unclear.  Your actual output versus your desired output is not clearly expressed.  Are you saying that `$string` is only retaining the last row's `msg` -- that would make sense.  If you are only trying to access `$string` then your [mcve] doesn't need to show any of the `if (is_array(... )` condition block.  Why do you have a loop breaking `return`?  We don't see where/why this would be a good idea for the code provided.  If you are searching for email addresses with the second pattern, it will not catch all email addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When already `while()` is executing then what's the need of `foreach()` inside it?

Do like below:

```
$query = "SELECT email_id, msg FROM emailtry";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    if (preg_match_all("/Dynamic Screen:\s+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\s+[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", $obj->msg, $notificationtype)){
        var_dump($notificationtype);
    }
    if (preg_match_all("/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", $obj->msg, $bodylogonused)){
        var_dump($bodylogonused);
    }
}
```

***Note:*** As @mickmackusa suggested, use `[\w-]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` in your code. (more concise)

```
$query = "SELECT email_id, msg FROM emailtry";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    if (preg_match_all("/Dynamic Screen:\s+[\w-]+\s+[\w-]+/", $obj->msg, $notificationtype)){
        var_dump($notificationtype);
    }
    if (preg_match_all("/[\w-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w-]+/", $obj->msg, $bodylogonused)){
        var_dump($bodylogonused);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mickmackusa  I am actually not good in regex, what I did is just helped OP to rectify his code to make it working. In case you have any  you can post answer. I will appreciate that

Comment: @mickmackusa  thanks for sharing code suggestion, added that, could you please have a look that everything fine. I am really bad in regex....Thanks

Comment: Well, as I commented under the question, there are valid email addresses that eill not be captured.